# Creating Axis Labels on Seaborn Countplot

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

I want to add axis labels to a Seaborn countplot I have created using the following code:

```
chart = sns.countplot(df_["HOURS"]).set_title("Number of Calls Reporting Burglary For Each Day of the Week")
```

I tried using the following method to create labels for the X and Y axes:

```
#.set(xlabel='Hour', ylabel='Number of Calls')
```

However, this returned:

```
AttributeError: 'Text' object has no property 'ylabel'
```

How can I add x and y labels on this plot?

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

chart.set(xlabel='', ylabel='')
plt.show()
```

Seaborn does not have the explicit methods for setting labels. Use matplotlib along with seaborn and it should work.